# What does * (asterisk) do when applied to a TensorFlow layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Currently reading a Python implementation of Inception-ResNet to assist in building a model in a different language (Deeplearning4j). This implementation is Inception-ResNet-v1 and I was trying to figure out how it implements the residual shortcuts in ResNet style.

In the following code block is `net += scale * up`.

```
# Inception-Renset-A
def block35(net, scale=1.0, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, scope=None, reuse=None):
    """Builds the 35x35 resnet block."""
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, 'Block35', [net], reuse=reuse):
        with tf.variable_scope('Branch_0'):
            tower_conv = slim.conv2d(net, 32, 1, scope='Conv2d_1x1')
        with tf.variable_scope('Branch_1'):
            tower_conv1_0 = slim.conv2d(net, 32, 1, scope='Conv2d_0a_1x1')
            tower_conv1_1 = slim.conv2d(tower_conv1_0, 32, 3, scope='Conv2d_0b_3x3')
        with tf.variable_scope('Branch_2'):
            tower_conv2_0 = slim.conv2d(net, 32, 1, scope='Conv2d_0a_1x1')
            tower_conv2_1 = slim.conv2d(tower_conv2_0, 32, 3, scope='Conv2d_0b_3x3')
            tower_conv2_2 = slim.conv2d(tower_conv2_1, 32, 3, scope='Conv2d_0c_3x3')
        mixed = tf.concat(3, [tower_conv, tower_conv1_1, tower_conv2_2])
        up = slim.conv2d(mixed, net.get_shape()[3], 1, normalizer_fn=None,
                         activation_fn=None, scope='Conv2d_1x1')
        net += scale * up
        if activation_fn:
            net = activation_fn(net)
    return net
```

Scale is a `double` between 0 and 1. `up` is a stack of layers, the last being a conv2d layer.

What specifically is happening with `scale * up`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each layer in `up` is being multiplied by the scalar value in `scale`. And then `net` is being redefined as `net + scale * up`. So `net` should have the same dimensions as `up`.

Comment: On second thought, is `scale` specifically scaling the layer *output* or is it scaling the parameters/config?

Comment: I'm just starting out with TensorFlow myself, but as far as I can tell it is scaling the output of a layer. This layer is defined with the TF-slim library, which you are probably familiar with. I've been reading up on slim from the [TF-slim github page](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/README.md).

Comment: Interesting I wonder if it's meant to normalize the output. I'm actually not familiar with TensorFlow, I'm writing in DL4J, but attempting to read a researcher's model.

Comment: I wish I could tell you for sure.